# when a database content deletes ,how can i redirect to same page using url argument passing method?

Tags: django

i want to delete a database content.bt after deletion utl goes to http://127.0.0.1:8004/login/delete_detail/6/ ..how can i redirect to success.html ie in the same page

```
class DeleteView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'success.html'
    success_url='/login/success'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DeleteView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        did = self.kwargs['did']
        q_obj = Quest.objects.filter(id=did)
        q_obj.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_success_url` method:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class DeleteView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'success.html'
    success_url='/login/success'
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DeleteView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        did = self.kwargs['did']
        q_obj = Quest.objects.filter(id=did)
        q_obj.delete()

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        return reverse_lazy('delete_detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.kwargs['did']})
```

Also instead of `TemplateView` you can use [`DeleteView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview) class:

```
class QuestDelete(DeleteView):
    model = Quest
    pk_url_kwarg = 'did'

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):         
        return reverse_lazy('delete_detail', kwargs = {'pk': self.kwargs['did']})
```

To use url's name you need to add name argument to the url pattern inside `urls.py` file like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('delete_detail', views.delete_detail, name='delete_detail'),
]
```

Comment: what is delete-detail ?

Comment: @Anjitha delete-detail is the name of url you want redirect to.

Comment: its not working...i also redirect to http://127.0.0.1:8010/login/delete_detail/5/ page

Answer (score 0):

You should override `get_success_url` method. For example:

```
def get_success_url(self):

     return reverse_lazy('delete-success')
```

Also, try to use named urls in your `success_url`

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('delete-success')
```